# Do a mv for all files with path changing according to a list

Tags: bash

I have two questions.

I have a file.txt with a name of a specie per line, for exemple:

```
specie1
specie2
specie3
...
```

and I would like to create a new dir called new_dir in each of the following paths

```
/specie_1/run_busco/run_specie_1_ok_v3/
/specie_2/run_busco/run_Specie_2_ok_v3/
/specie_3/run_busco/run_Specie_3_ok_v3/
```

to get:

```
/specie_1/run_busco/run_specie_1_ok_v3/new_dir
/specie_2/run_busco/run_Specie_2_ok_v3/new_dir
/specie_3/run_busco/run_Specie_3_ok_v3/new_dir
```

And my second question is quite the same but now I would like to move some files into the new_dir created, for exemple I'll have some files into run_specie_X_ok_v3/ such as:

```
/specie_1/run_busco/run_specie_1_ok_v3/
seq1.faa
seq2.faa
seq3.faa

/specie_2/run_busco/run_Specie_2_ok_v3/
seq1.faa
seq2.faa
seq3.faa

/specie_3/run_busco/run_Specie_3_ok_v3/
seq1.faa
seq2.faa
seq3.faa
```

And I would like to do a `mv *faa new_dir` for all directories.

Have you an idea how to to it? I mean my issue is because the path change all the time in depending on the specie_name.

I have tried to do something like that:

```
cat file.txt | while read line
do
    echo mkdir '/'$file'/run_busco/run_'$file'_ok_v3/new_dir'
done
```

and then I run all the scripts generated. 
And the same for the second question:

```
cat file.txt | while read line
do
    echo mv '/'$file'/run_busco/run_'$file'_ok_v3/*.faa new_dir'
done
```

Comment: Did you try something from this? This is a lot of requirements to be asking without sharing any code

Comment: Yes, of course you can do it. You can isolate the `specie` and `x` with simple *parameter expansions* (either string indexes or substring removal) and then use the two substrings to form the paths you need and perform the move. What have you tried?

Comment: I updated my post, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `$file` with `$line` and you dont need echo

```
cat file.txt | while read line; do mkdir "/$line/run_busco/run_$line_ok_v3/new_dir"; done


cat file.txt | while read line; do mv "/$line /run_busco/run_${line}_ok_v3/*.faa new_dir"; done
```

Comment: I have an issue ah the part `run_$line_ok_v3` it says: No such file or directory because it understands the following path `/$line/run_busco_/run_/*.faa` and skip the `$line_ok_v3` part.

Comment: mv needs two arguments, first is source path and second is target. I already saw that you have problem there

Comment: Here is my script : `cat file_all_species_name.txt | while read line; do mv "/path/data/$line/run_busco/run_$line_BUSCO_v3/single_copy_busco_sequences/*.fna /path/data/$line/run_busco/run_$line_BUSCO_v3/single_copy_busco_sequences/single_copy_busco_nucleotides"; done` and I have two issues; first  is the missing destination but I yet put the path destination and the second is that the source path is incorrect since it prints :`'/path/data/specie_2/run_busco/run_/single_copy_busco_sequences/*.fna` and not `'/path/data/specie_2/run_busco/run_specie_2_BUSCO_V3/single_copy_busco_sequences/*.fna`

Comment: Ok now it's still about the missing destination I do not understand mv work like `mv /path/source /path/destination` as I wrote in my script above.

Comment: In your  mv statement I only see source path, source and destination parts needed to be written with space in between them